# Yii2 - How to return FK data in model

Tags: php, yii2

I have a model called Account.php:

```
class Account extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
```

The table has the following fields:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['company_id', 'account_type_id', 'default_rate_id'], 'integer'],
        [['prepaid_only', 'email_send', 'active', 'archived'], 'boolean'],
        [['address_mailing', 'email_addresses'], 'string'],
        [['archived_date'], 'safe'],
        [['number'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 90]
    ];
}
```

To retrieve data based on a Foreign Key (FK) I am using the following functions:

```
public function getAccountType()
{
    return $this->hasOne(AccountType::className(), ['id' => 'account_type_id']);
}
public function getAccountTypeName()
{
    return $this->accountType->name;
}

public function getRate()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Rate::className(), ['id' => 'default_rate_id']);
}
public function getRateName()
{
    return $this->rate->name;
}
```

**QUESTION:** The code works for getAccountTypeName, but for getRateName I am getting the following error:

*Trying to get property of non-object*

Why am I getting that error on only one of the functions?

Comment: Can you check whats on `getRate()` ?

Comment: It simply means you don't have corresponding rate for this account, or that your rate relation is not well defined.

Comment: @soju I think it means that I don't have a corresponding rate for the account. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.